# Stop certain files redirecting in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Can someone tell me how to modify my `.htaccess` file to not redirect `.txt` files please.

The `.htaccess` file redirects everything from `http` to `https` but I want to exclude any `.txt` files from redirecting.

This is the current content of my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN Really_Simple_SSL_HSTS
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;     includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
Header always set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
</IfModule>
# END Really_Simple_SSL_HSTS

# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[2.5.20]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding another condition to the rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.txt$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Although you'd probably want to make sure the URL does not end in `.txt`, rather than simply does not contain `.txt`. eg. `!\.txt$`. It would be marginally more efficient to do this in the `RewriteRule` pattern instead of using an additional `RewriteCond` directive. eg. `RewriteRule !\.txt$ https://....`